# My WAN IP isn't the same as my public IP (Assigned by my ISP)

Tags: networking, router, ip, wan, ddns

Let’s say something about the problem (If there's some like that).

#### What’s my configuration?

I have Fibertel ISP (Argentina) with a modem and a router behind it.

The server is connected through wire and running an Ubuntu server 16.04.

The router is configured to forwarding the ports that I'm using to my server.

#### What about the connection?

When I look into web admin of the router, I see an IP like `10.107.xxx.xxx`. When I go to **whatsmyip.org**, my IP seems to be like `190.151.xxx.xxx`.

When I try to connect through SSH using the first IP, all goes well, but with the public IP (The one in `whatsmyip.org`) nothing works fine.

#### Some notes

I already try with a window server too (Yeah, I truly sorry, but I have to). I already check my router configuration to permit all the traffic like SSH, VPN, etc.

I flush all IPtables in my Ubuntu server (Just in case).

I use **DynDns** as DDNS.

At least, everything was working a month ago. I just move the server to my house and then nothing works. Of course, I checked it with my ISP provider and it doesn't seems to be anything making troubles in the middle.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit:**

The problem was that my ISP wasn’t providing me a public IP in the standard package of services (it never crossed my mind that services like this could in fact exist). They said me a couple of times “You have to hire a public IP” but I was like “They really mean 'Static IP'.” Anyhow, they are the only provider in almost the country doing that.

Thanks for all the help and I hope I can help anyone in the same situation!

Comment: Just a side note... Most isp's place their customers behind a CGN (Commercial Grade NAT). This will sometimes mess up things like trying to configure servers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT

Comment: If your ISP is using CGN, you cannot forward the ports where the ISP does the NAT, and your ISP won't/can't do that for you since it can only do it for one customer per port on the NAT. The ISPs don't really care since most residential ISPs have a clause in the terms of service which prohibit you from running servers or services from your network to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `10.107.XXX.XXX` is your router WAN address. It does not look like public IP. The range `10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255` is reserved for private networks. My guess is you are behind ISP's NAT. If I'm right, there are (at least) two daisy-chained NATs: on some ISP machine and on your router.

To reach your router from the outside you need to ask your ISP to forward desired ports to your router, or ask for separate public IP just for your router (ISP may charge you extra for this).

Comment: Thanks! I already talk with them, and they say that none port is being blocked, but...I'll try with static public IP. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my ISP wasn’t providing me a public IP in the standard package of services (it never crossed my mind that services like this could in fact exist). They said me a couple of times “You have to hire a public IP” but I was like “They really mean 'Static IP'.” Anyhow, they are the only provider in almost the country doing that.

Thanks for all the help and I hope I can help anyone in the same situation!